# Scala Spark - Cannot resolve a column name

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This should be pretty straightforward, but I'm having an issue with the following code:

```scala
val test = spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .csv("sample.csv")

test.select("Type").show()
test.select("Provider Id").show()
```

`test` is a dataframe like so:

| Type | Provider Id |
| --- | --- |
| A | asd |
| A | bsd |
| A | csd |
| B | rrr |

```scala
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
cannot resolve '`Provider Id`' given input columns: [Type, Provider Id];;
'Project ['Provider Id]
```

It selected and shows the `Type` column just fine but couldn't get it to work for the `Provider Id`. I wondered if it were because the column name had a space, so I tried using backticks, removing and replacing the space, but nothing seemed to work. Also, it ran fine when I'm using Spark libraries 3.x but doesn't work when I'm using Spark 2.1.x (meanwhile I need to use 2.1.x)

Additional: I tried changing the CSV column order from `Type` - `Provider Id` to `Provider Id` then `Type`. The error was the opposite, `Provider Id` shows but for `Type` it's throwing an exception now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show part of your csv, and also part of code where you read it with spark?

Comment: @qaziqarta Added the read part, the csv looks the same with the dataframe. Have no problem using looking (.show) at `test`, it's only when I select a column that it throws an error. Or do you need to see something else from the csv? Thanks

Comment: Could you print the column names from the dataframe schema: `println(test.columns)` and check if you use the column name correctly? you can also try `test.select(test.columns(1)).show()` to check if it works when you use the column name from the schema

Comment: Is it possible that "Provider Id" in csv contains some whitespace at the end? E.g. space or windows newline (\r)?

Comment: Turns out it was due to byte order mark (\uFEFF or something) showing up on the read dataframe. Not sure why spark 2 has this issue while spark 3 don't, but I can probably try to fix this. Thanks a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

```
test.printSchema()
```

You can use the result from `printSchema()` to see how exactly spark read your column in, then use that in your code.